# Do Intel processors/chipsets have their own LAN chips now?

Tags: audio, motherboard, lan, chipset

I was looking at the specs of this [Intel chipset](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201835/intel-h470-chipset.html), when I noticed that it mentions having *"Integrated LAN"*, *"Intel® HD Audio Technology"*, *"Intel® Smart Sound Technology*". I thought you needed separate chips for this stuff, like Realtek chips. So does it mean that this chipset has its own LAN and Audio chipsets and it won't require a separate chip for these functions?

From the link:
*"Integrated LAN: Integrated LAN indicates the presence of an integrated Intel Ethernet MAC or presence of the LAN ports built into the system board."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the chipset rather than the actual processor. The chipset is the Platform Controller Hub (PCH) through which the processor talks to SATA disks, PCI and PCIe devices and a multitude of other things.

Intel have long had their own line of ethernet chips and controllers, integrating one into the PCH is not surprising at all. I personally have worked on projects with the [Intel i210 ethernet controller.](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/64400/intel-ethernet-controller-i210at.html)

So yes. Your motherboard can have integrated LAN built into the motherboard controller.

But no. It is not built in to the processor.

Comment: yes, i was actually talking about the chipset, but mistakenly wrote processor in the title.

Comment: i have another question though, is the PCH same as southbridge/chipset/motherboard controller? or are they just different names intel vs amd gave them?

Comment: The "southbridge" is largely obsolete with the functionality being [merged into the PCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_(computing)#Current_status), but yes, the [Platform Controller Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub) is essentially the modern "northbridge" since the memory controller and GPU PCIe (northbridge functions) were moved into the CPU itself. But yes, the PCH is essentially the motherboard controller.

Comment: @Sam There may well even be extra chips that break out the PCH PCIe lanes and other devices and provide *more* devices such as Ethernet, SATA, and whatever else, but that doesn't mean that those functions cannot get integrated into the PCH itself.